# Export gridview in a pdf file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview, export

I want to export `gridview` in a `pdf` file.

**Source Code**

```
<div id="divppdf" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="grdLoanInquery" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PK_CustomerID" EmptyDataText="Record does not exists." Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" Height="121px" PageSize="5" ShowFooter="True" Width="100%"
    OnPageIndexChanging="grdLoanInquery_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="grdLoanInquery_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PK_CustomerID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PK_CustomerID">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" SortExpression="FirstName">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BillingAmt" HeaderText="Billing Amount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" SortExpression="BillingAmt">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DpAmt" HeaderText="DP Amount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" SortExpression="DpAmt">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LoanAmt" HeaderText="Loan Amount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" SortExpression="LoanAmt">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="InterestRate" HeaderText="Interest Rate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" SortExpression="InterestRate">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="More" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgMore" runat="server" Height="22px" ImageUrl="~/Images/MoreDetail.png" ToolTip="More Details" Width="28px" CommandArgument='
    <%# Eval("PK_CustomerID") %>
    ' CommandName="more" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Document" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDetail" runat="server" Height="22px" ImageUrl="~/Images/document1.png" ToolTip="Document Details" Width="28px" CommandArgument='
    <%# Eval("PK_CustomerID") %>
    ' CommandName="document" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Record Does not exists.">
            </asp:Label>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <FooterStyle CssClass="gridFooter" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <HeaderStyle BorderStyle="None" CssClass="gridHeader" />
        <PagerStyle CssClass="gridHeader" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#A8D3FF" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
 divppdf.Visible = true;
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
 Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
 divppdf.RenderControl(hw);
 StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
 Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80f, 80f, -2f, 35f);
 HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
 pdfDoc.Open();
 //head.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, page.Width / 8, page.Height - pdfDoc.TopMargin + head.TotalHeight, writer.DirectContent);
 //pdfDoc.Add(headerTbl);   
 htmlparser.Parse(sr);
 pdfDoc.Close();
 Response.Write(pdfDoc);
 Response.End();
```

**Explanation:**
My problem is that I am getting 'error' as below.
[image: image of error]

Mainly I am not able to get contents of `div` tag in above code.

```
 divppdf.RenderControl(hw);
```

**Note:**

This page inside of master page.

**update**
This is my error.

> Control 'ContentPlaceHolder1_grdLoanInquery' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: Your attached image is not clear...plz add the error you getting...

Comment: i have attached my error msg.

Comment: The error said: `must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server` - Please confirm that you satisfy this statement?

Comment: This solution http://www.webblogsforyou.com/control-gridview1-of-type-gridview-must-be-placed-inside-a-form-tag-with-runatserver/ helped me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please override Render Event, it may help you.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
  EnsureChildControls();
  base.Render(writer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering div you should render the GridView.
Following code show you, how you can achieve that thing.

**Code:**

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf");

Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

grdLoanInquery.AllowPaging = false;

grdLoanInquery.DataBind();

grdLoanInquery.RenderControl(hw);

StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);

HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

pdfDoc.Open();

htmlparser.Parse(sr);

pdfDoc.Close();

Response.Write(pdfDoc);

Response.End();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{

}
```

And in `.aspx` File place this `EnableEventValidation="false"`.